# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, pdo

intento hacer que una tabla inserte y otra haga un update ,la del insert funciona bien ,pero la del update me marca ese error
adjunto el codigo donde aparece ese error:

```
try{
$actualizar = $conexion -> prepare("UPDATE talleres SET taller_cupo = (:cupos - 1) WHERE taller_id=:taller_reg");
$actualizar -> bindParam(':taller_reg', $taller_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$actualizar -> bindParam(':cupos', $cupos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ejecutar= $actualizar -> execute(); 

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En el código que compartes no veo motivo para ese error. ¿En qué línea indica que ocurre?

Comment: Coloca la otra parte de tu código para ver que tienes.